# Simplest way to edit EXIF ImageDescription or IPTC Caption-Abstract?

Tags: finder, photos, metadata, exif

On Windows 10 (don't know about earlier versions), all you have to do is click on the image file in Windows Explorer and then edit the file details. The updated caption is written directly to the file.

I can't find anything this simple on Mac OS X. (I can view a caption with the Finder and with Preview, but can't change it.) I can add metadata in the Photos app, but there seems to be no way to sync it back to the original file. (I assume the new file written when you Export has the metadata, but that doesn't do what I want.)

I have my own app in the Mac App Store that can do this (ExifChanger), but I'm surprised that there's no way built into OS X to do it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope. Without something 3rd party such as exiftool or a GUI-based  editor I don't think you can make changes to the EXIF data on OS X.

Comment: Very clear answer... thanks! Will wait a bit to see if anyone else comes up with something that neither you nor I can find.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what your actual question is.  It's clear you're not looking to find a way to edit EXIF data because you publish your own app to do that.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My app is not a simple solution because it requires an app to be purchased and installed. For many Mac users, this is out of the question--they use only what came with the computer, and if there's something there they don't get, they ask at the Genius Bar. I thought I stated my question clearly in the title: "Simplest way to edit EXIF ImageDescription or IPTC Caption-Abstract?"

Comment: dr: Can you post your comment as an answer so I can check it?